# Перезагрузка сервера с веб-страницы

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, администрирование

День добрый! Есть вопрос, касательно такой функции, как перезагрузка сервера с веб-страницы. Подобная опция есть у заббикса, которая срабатывает на триггеры, и отправляет команды, но моя задача, организовать примерно то же самое, но, желательно на питоне. Если чуть точнее, то нужена "кнопка" на веб-странице, которая  могла бы отправлять запросы на сервер. Искал в гугле, но ничего не нашёл. Есть какое-то подобное решение? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Берите абсолютно любой веб-фреймворк для питона и делайте что вашей душе угодно

Comment: А чё не `webmin`?

Comment: Для подобной штуки можно накидать телеграм-бота, пишешь в телеграм команду '/перезагрузить ос' и сервер перезагружается. Аналогично со всеми остальными командами. По моему это безопаснее чем кнопка в интернете

Answer (score 1):

А вы можете включать и выключать устройства из командной строки?
Если да, то напрашивается костыльное решение:

По нажатию кнопки генерировать файл флаг на локальной системе, который будет проверяться задачей из крона или из юнита systemd и выполнять указанные действия.

Например в зависимости от существования файла, или содержащихся в нём аргументов

Comment: Появилась немного другая задача, на самом деле. Это должно быть как что-то по типу удалённого управления сервером. В общем, было бы неплохо вводить разные команды, (не только reboot), и, чтобы они выполнялись на сервере.

Comment: ну, если развивать совет) - то всё тоже самое, в уникальный файл записывается команда - которую крон выполняет.  другой вопрос если нужно видеть результат вводимой команды (если только видеть - перенаправление вывода в другой файл который читать и выводить на странице), а если взаимодействовать, по сути аля - терминал, тогда проще воспользоваться webmin - там есть консоль

Answer (score 0):

На питоне можно попробовать сделать так:

```
import os
os.system("reboot now")
```

Этот код выполнит консольную команду для перезагрузки всей системы. Для выполнения этого действия скрипт должен выполняться от пользователя `root`.

Comment: А подобное можно пробовать с подключёнными устройствами к серверу? Допустим, плееры.

Comment: Ну эта команда просто перезагружает систему

Comment: А если нужно перезагрузить отдельное устройство?

Comment: В каком смысле перезагрузить? Отключить и подключить опять?

Comment: Да, перезагрузить и включить снова. Так же из формы,

Comment: Не всякое устройство и не всякий фреймворк поддерживает режим горячей смены. Вам надо откорректировать вопрос.